# Is it possible to extract some expressions from modulus brckets?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an expression:

$$\left| x-y-a\cdot \left( \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2} \right) \right|$$

where $a>0$, $x>0$ and $y>0$. Can I make something with it to get:

$$\left| x-y \right| \cdot SomethingElse$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course:
$$\left| x-y-a\cdot \left( \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2} \right) \right| = \left| x-y\right|\left| 1-\frac{a\cdot \left( \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2} \right)}{x-y} \right|$$